# adding an if statement to a mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

`p1.username` always has a value that's foreign to `VB_user` table. The problem is that `p2.username` has a default value of `0` and it's not a value in the `VB_user` table. So if I run the query it will only show the results if `p2.username` doesn't have a value of zero. How can I make it so if `p2.username` has the value of `0` it will show in my results, since `VB_user.userid` doesn't have a `0` can it, can I still show something?

In other words, I want to be able to show the results of `p2.username` even if its value is `0`.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT p.r1, p.r2, p.rounds, p.whenmatch, p.created, p.status, p.lid, p1.userid AS userid1, p1.username AS challenger, p2.userid AS userid2, p2.username AS challenged, p3.lname 
        FROM AB_league_match p 
        JOIN VB_user p1 on p.challenger = p1.userid 
        JOIN VB_user p2 on p.challenged = p2.userid 
        JOIN AB_league p3 on p.lid = p3.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.r1, p.r2, p.rounds, p.whenmatch, p.created, p.status, p.lid, p1.userid AS userid1, p1.username AS challenger, p2.userid AS userid2, p2.username AS challenged, p3.lname 
        FROM AB_league_match p 
        JOIN VB_user p1 on p.challenger = p1.userid 
        LEFT JOIN VB_user p2 on p.challenged = p2.userid 
        JOIN AB_league p3 on p.lid = p3.id
```

Comment: I forgot about left joins :/ Thanks for the help. Will accept you answer.